# 多変量時系列データにおいてモデルに入力するデータをどのように選べばいいかという論文はありますか

Tags: 深層学習

例えば、100個の多変量時系列データがあって、一つの時系列データを予測したいとします。
このような場合に、100個のデータから本当に予測に必要なデータを選ぶ方法はどのようなものがあるでしょうか。

さらに、もしもこの100個のデータがそれぞれ数値でなく、画像やテキストである場合、どのような手法が考えられるでしょうか。

以上のことに関係する論文があったら教えていただきたいです。自分では見つけることができませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

一般的な話としては特徴選択/Feature selectionで探すと関係した論文が見つかります。

https://scholar.google.co.jp/scholar?hl=ja&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Feature+Selection%3A&btnG=

検索キーワードにtime seriesを追加すると時系列に特化した論文も多数ありました。